# Can't Image upload to Amazon S3 Bucket from Ckeditor5 [ckeditor]

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ckeditor

I am tried to upload image to Amazon S3 bucket from CKEDITOR5. I can not upload image.

When I tried to upload image in ckeditor the below error showing.

[image]

As per documentation, I changed Amazon S3 bucket details in ckeditor config file.

But I can see the images list which was uploaded in S3 bucket manually.

I need to upload images and files to Amazon s3 bucket in CKEditor 5